# How to extend the text along the entire textPath in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I make the text on a path ([see screenshot](http://yadi.sk/d/Hcn85Jxh0unbg)) extend so that it follows the entire textPath?

I have tried using the [`method` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextPathElementMethodAttribute) value `stretch` but it doesn't work like I expect - it doesn't stretch the text along the path.

Is there a way to make this work in all browsers?

Comment: Do you mean to make the text fit all the way along the entire length of the path? Or are you talking about the `method` attribute, http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextPathElementMethodAttribute?

Comment: yes, I mean the method attribute - [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextPathElementMethodAttribute)

Comment: here is screenshot [linlk](http://yadi.sk/d/Hcn85Jxh0unbg). My problem is I can't stretch <textPath> by attribute method

Comment: Is it this effect you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/zkZ2n/? (Works in Opera and Chrome)

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. But how does it reach for other browsers who support svg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to spread out the text over the entire textPath is to use the `textLength` attribute. Also see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800478/svg-textpath-determine-when-text-goes-beyond-the-path) for how to compute a good value for `textLength`. Here's how to do it:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 300" version="1.1">
     <defs>
         <path id="s3" d="M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70" />
     </defs>
     <text font-size="20">
         <textPath xlink:href="#s3" textLength="205">
           Short text
         </textPath>
     </text>
     <use xlink:href="#s3" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
 </svg>
```

Viewable example: http://jsfiddle.net/zkZ2n/

[image]

Here's the bugreport for Firefox not supporting `textLength`: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=569722

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.